# Django ORM: move filter after annotate subquery

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

This Django ORM statement:

```py
Model.objects.all() \
    .annotate(
        ord=Window(
            expression=RowNumber(),
            partition_by=F('related_id'),
            order_by=[F("date_created").desc()]
        )
    ) \
    .filter(ord=1) \
    .filter(date_created__lte=some_datetime)
```

Leads to the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
      id, related_id, values, date_created
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY related_id
        ORDER BY date_created DESC
      ) AS ord
    FROM model_table
    WHERE date_created <= 2022-02-24 00:00:00+00:00
)
WHERE ord = 1
```

As you can see, the `date_created__lte` filter gets applied on the inner query. Is it possible to control statement location preciser and move the filter outside, like `ord`?

Comment: use [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

Comment: @sahasrara62 I see no way for this – the `Subquery` object is used for filtering or annotated selecting values (SQL `SELECT`, `WHERE`), but I need a subquery to use inside `FROM` statement 

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can move the date_created__lte filter before the annotate method to make sure it is applied to the base query. This will improve the query performance too because the annotate method works on a smaller, filtered dataset.

```
Model.objects.filter(date_created__lte=some_datetime) \
    .annotate(
        ord=Window(
            expression=RowNumber(),
            partition_by=F('related_id'),
            order_by=[F("date_created").desc()]
        )
    ) \
    .filter(ord=1)
```

Comment: THanks for the reply! But `date_created__lte` filter already gets applied to the inner query (ignoring order of `filter` methods), and I need to make it applied to the outer query, after `.filter(ord=1)`.

Comment: Also, this order of filtering changes the results. In my real code, I need to perform more complicated logic, which requires data exactly *after* filtering by annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve the results I want: applying a filter, `date_created__lte` in this example, outside of annotated query.

```py
sub = Model.objects.all() \
    .annotate(
        ord=Window(
            expression=RowNumber(),
            partition_by=F('related_id'),
            order_by=[F('date_created').desc()]
        )
    ) \
    .filter(ord=1)

Model.objects.all() \
    .filter(id__in=sub.values_list('id')) \
    .filter(date_created__lte=some_datetime)
```

However, this is not a code I want, it's bad from performance point of view due to HASH JOIN. Of course, I can write a raw SQL query, parse values by Django ORM, but this looks too heavy for a simple nested subquery. So, a better answer is appreciated